# addClass with jquery in existing Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a class with jQuery to my code, but it doesn't work.

I would like to have an extra class for the previous steps of the form. How am i able to do this? If I type `addclass` to the previous steps it's only visible if I press the previous button.

Here is the jQuery Code and the HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
    allWells = $('.setup-content'),
    allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn'),
    allPrevBtn = $('.prevBtn');

  allWells.hide();

  navListItems.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
      $item = $(this);

    if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
      navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-next');
      $item.addClass('btn-primary');
      allWells.hide();
      $target.show();
      $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
    }
  });

  allPrevBtn.click(function() {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
      curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
      prevStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().prev().children("a");

    prevStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
  });

  allNextBtn.click(function() {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
      curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
      nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
      curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
      isValid = true;

    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
      if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
        isValid = false;
        $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
      }
    }

    if (isValid)
      nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');

  });
});

$('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <title>leasing</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/costum.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="stepwizard row col-md-12">

      <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">

        <div class="stepwizard-step">
          <a href="#step-1" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fab fa-font-awesome-flag"></i> Hey there!</a>
        </div>

        <div class="stepwizard-step">
          <a href="#step-2" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Information</a>
        </div>

        <div class="stepwizard-step">
          <a href="#step-3" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-store"></i> Store</a>
        </div>

        <div class="stepwizard-step">
          <a href="#step-4" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-bicycle"></i> Bicycle</a>
        </div>

        <div class="stepwizard-step">
          <a href="#step-5" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-user-shield"></i> Insurance</a>
        </div>

        <div class="stepwizard-step">
          <a href="#step-6" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-user-shield"></i> Shipment</a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <form class="leasingform col-md-10 col-xs-8" role="form" action="" method="post">

      <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="welcome-text col-md-12">
              <h3>Hey there and welcome,</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
                no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lore</p>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
              <input maxlength="100" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" type="text">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
              <input maxlength="100" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" type="text">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
              <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label class="control-label">Address</label>
              <textarea required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your address"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
              <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" type="text">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
              <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" type="text">
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Previous</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
              <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
              <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" type="text">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Previous</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row setup-content" id="step-4">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
              <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
              <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" type="text">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Previous</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row setup-content" id="step-5">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
              <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
              <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" type="text">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Previous</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row setup-content" id="step-6">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Previous</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your question is unfortunately quite unclear: Which element should have a new css class? When should this css-class be added? Can't you add it to the html directly? What have you tried already?

Comment: Are you asking, 'How can I add a class to an element after pressing next button'?

Comment: Hey @Capricorn i want to add an extra class to the steps that already finished/completed.

i tried already to add this:

nextStepWizard.addClass('class').trigger('click');

but it doesn't work.

I'm not good in jQuery.

Comment: @Esaith Yes. That's what i need!

Answer (score 0):

To add a new css-class to a `nextBtn` that has been clicked, you may adjust the respective click-listener. The following example adds the css-class `step-done` after the button has been clicked and all validation has been successful.

```
allNextBtn.click(function() {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
    curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
    /* ...your other code remains here... */

    if (isValid) {
      // Do the following to add a css-class to the last step button
      $(this).addClass('step-done');

      // Do the following to add a css-class to the div containing the last step
      curStep.addClass('step-done');

      nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
    }

});
```

Comment: I dont think it was to add the css-class to the nextBtn itself but the step that they were on. Is this correct, @Aderion?

Comment: If that's the case, he can just reuse the `curStep` variable and do `curStep.addClass('step-done')`

Comment: @Esaith Kind of. I want to change the color of the first step if i do the second, than the second when i do the third. I think you get it.

Comment: I extended the answer to cover both of the scenarios. Next time, please try to make your question a little clearer to get help faster ;)

Comment: @Capricorn Thank you for your help. But curStep.addClass('step-done'); doesn't work. It's weird. Thats what i already tried. Damd.

I think the key is to link the css class to <a href="#step-1" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fab fa-font-awesome-flag"></i> Hey there!</a>

Comment: Does it add the css-class? If that's the case, your css rule for altering the styling might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i managed to get it work, like i want it.

i had to take

```js
$('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]')
```

and build it in like this:

```js
  allPrevBtn.click(function(){
      var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
          curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
          prevStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().prev().children("a");
    
    $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').removeClass('step-done');

          prevStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
  });
```

to remove the class for the previous steps.

to add it i managed it like this:

```js
  allNextBtn.click(function(){
      var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
          curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
          nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
          curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
          isValid = true;

      $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
          if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
              isValid = false;
              $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
          }
      }

      if (isValid)
    $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').addClass('step-done');
          nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
  });
```

Thank you for your time :)